# If I create a PNG image in photoshop with 85% opacity, how can I maintain that same level of opacity when I add it to my iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

If I create a PNG image in Photoshop and lower the opacity so it's 85% opaque, how can I maintain that same level of transparency when I add it to my iOS app?

I'm trying to set the background image of a UILabel to be this image, but the background image for the UILabel is fully opaque in my iOS app.  Here's my code...

```
[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"labelBackground.png"]]];
```

Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Comment: Are you using 8-bit or 24-bit PNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I'd put an `UIImageView` containing the image behind your `UILabel`. Then make sure your UILabel and UIImageView backgroundColors are both set to `[UIColor clearColor]`. That's how I do it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `lbl.opaque = NO;`?

Comment: no, I didn't try that, and I've already modified my code enough to where I can no longer try it without reverting.  Anyhow, would that also make the text in the label transparent?  If so, I need to avoid that.

Comment: `opaque=YES` means that the entire rectangle defined by the view's frame will be filled in at 100% opacity, hence why you won't see any transparency in the background.  If you want any sort of transparency, you need to set it to NO.  The text will still be drawn at 100% opacity (unless you change the `textColor` property to a semi-transparent color).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, iOS preserves opacity for PNG images.

I think I have an idea of what MAY be wrong (and pardon me for making any wrong assumptions)...

In photoshop, when saving a PNG image, there's an option to "Save Transparency" or something like that. Make sure that is checked before you save the PNG.

If this is not the problem, you can always use:

```
UIImageView.opacity = 85.0f/100.0f;
```

Let me know if this solves your problem :)

Comment: Replace UIImageView with your actual instance name of course ;)

Comment: Whoops realized you're not using UIImageView (I jumped the gun there). As long as you save the image with the transparency though, it should all work fine. I've used semi-transparent backgrounds in my apps so I know for sure it's possible.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know, but I went ahead and implement Sam V's approach and it works now.  Must have something to do with the colorWithPatternImage method.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some background issues just like you, but I learned that ***most*** UIView subclasses have a backgroundView property which is accessed like this:

```
[aView backgroundView];
```

or

```
aView.backgroundView = someView;
```

UIImageViews keep the opacity of images. With these two things in mind you can just do:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]];

myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

myLabel.backgroundView = imageView;
```

I hope you find this useful.